# How do I make a Markdown table of two columns out of a list whose items alternate to each column?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, markdown

I have a long list of common abbreviations for words in periodical titles. In the list, the full word is followed by its abbreviation. For example:

- Administration
- Admin.
- Applied
- Appl.
- Administrative
- Administ.
- Approximate
- Approx.

I want to turn the list into a Markdown table, like this:

| Word | Abbreviation |
| --- | --- |
| Administration | Admin. |
| Applied | Appl. |

The problem is that doing this by hand would take forever. So, I'm looking for some way to do this faster. If it helps, all of the abbreviated forms end with a period (.).

I've looked online but couldn't find anything for this. That's why I'm asking here. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume that we have input file with list from your question. We can fill it using below command:

```
cat <<EOF > words+abbrs.txt
Administration
Admin.
Applied
Appl.
Administrative
Administ.
Approximate
Approx.
EOF
```

Creation of Markdown table is possible on Ubuntu using simple scripting as shown below:

- dumb step-by-step method

  ```
  # write table header
  echo "**Word** | **Abbreviation**" > table.md
  echo "- | -" >> table.md

  # extract odd lines as words to file words.txt
  awk 'NR%2==1' words+abbrs.txt > words.txt
  # extract even lines as abbreviations to file abbrs.txt
  awk 'NR%2==0' words+abbrs.txt > abbrs.txt

  # combine columns from words.txt and abbrs.txt with '|' separator
  paste -d '|' words.txt abbrs.txt >> table.md
  ```
- smart one-liner method (thanks to @steeldriver)

  ```
  { printf '%s\n' '**Word** | **Abbreviation**' '-|-'; paste -d '|' - - < words+abbrs.txt; } > table.md
  ```

You will get the Markdown file with the following contents:

> ```
> $ cat table.md 
> **Word** | **Abbreviation**
> - | -
> Administration|Admin.
> Applied|Appl.
> Administrative|Administ.
> Approximate|Approx.
> ```

So it will be rendered to HTML as

> | **Word** | **Abbreviation** |
> | --- | --- |
> | Administration | Admin. |
> | Applied | Appl. |
> | Administrative | Administ. |
> | Approximate | Approx. |

---

More info about used tools:

- `man awk` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/awk.1posix.html);
- `man paste` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/paste.1.html)
- [The GNU Awk User’s Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents)
- [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)
- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html)

Comment: Couldn't you avoid the awks and intermediate files altogether here? ex. `{ printf '%s\n' '**Word**|**Abbreviation**' '-|-'; paste -d '|' - - < words+abbrs.txt; }`

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, added. Could you please recommend me a good AWK and Bash old-school comprehensive online howto or book?

Comment: I usually find myself referring to [The GNU Awk User’s Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) for awk stuff (it's pretty good about highlighting where gawk differs from other implementations). For bash itself I'm not sure really - I like [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) - obviously the man page is comprehensive but I find it difficult to navigate.

Comment: Thanks, added both pages to bookmarks. https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html also looks good.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use Pandoc, it can convert from CSV to Markdown. Assuming you have a file of words one per line like [in N0rbert's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1383510/158442), you can convert it to a CSV using `paste -d, - -`, and then send it to Pandoc:

```
% (printf "%s\n" Word Abbreviation; cat input-file) | paste -d, - - | pandoc -f csv -t markdown_phpextra
| Word           | Abbreviation |
|----------------|--------------|
| Administration | Admin.       |
| Applied        | Appl.        |
| Administrative | Administ.    |
| Approximate    | Approx.      |
```

Giving:

| Word | Abbreviation |
| --- | --- |
| Administration | Admin. |
| Applied | Appl. |
| Administrative | Administ. |
| Approximate | Approx. |

(Further formatting of the heading is probably not required since table headers are usually formatted differently.)